# regexp_replace in teradata for date value

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I am using regexp_replace function in Teradata but encounters the below issues

I am looking to replace datevalue to YYYYMMDD.

Below is the query i have used

select RegExp_Replace('20230320',[0-9]{8},'YYYYMMDD')

error I get is " expected something between. and [ "

how do I achieve that in Teradata?

Comment: i think i have found issue as i didnt  include single quote was throwing error

Comment: Yes, the pattern must be passed as string